# Test what number is \thePagewiseLineNumber

Tags: conditionals, lineno

I want to test (not to print) if the actual line is the ***x*** line of a page.

With the help of the `lineno` package I able to know if the actual line is the ***x*** line of the document, testing what number is  `\thelinenumber`. Also I can print the line of the page in margin or even in line itself with `\thePagewiseLineNumber` but unlike  `\thelinenumber`, the control sequence `\thePagewiseLineNumber` cannot be used to test if the line number of page  is greater, less or equal than ***x*** because seem that is not really a counter, so some like `\ifnum\thePagewiseLineNumber > 1 A \else B \fi` produce  a "Missing number" error.

Let me explain better with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\pagewiselinenumbers
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{gray!50}}

\def\testinglinenumber{\noindent
Line \thePagewiseLineNumber\ 
(\thelinenumber\ in global count) --- 
% \ifnum\thePagewiseLineNumber>1   % Do not work (Missing number error)
\ifnum\thelinenumber>0 
  I am NOT in first line \else 
  I am in first line \fi\par}

\begin{document}

\testinglinenumber  % OK  because is still in first page 
\testinglinenumber  % OK because is still in first page
{\color{gray!50} \lipsum[1-4] More text \par More text \par } % only dummy text 

% the page break goes here
\testinglinenumber  % Wrong test, but I cannot test 
                    % \ifnum\thePagewiseLineNumber > 1 ....

\testinglinenumber  % Result of test OK but purely coincidental     
\end{document}
```

I've been diving in the code of `lineno.sty` to try to fish the right pagewise line counter (or make it) but it was deep water to me.

Some ideas with or without `lineno`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it's a little tricky to get this right. The command `\thePageWiseNumber` is an unexpandable command, which is why saying `\ifnum\thePageWiseNumber` fails. Usually the way to get output from unexpandable commands is that they store their output in a macro. Looking at the code for `\thePageWiseNumber`, it just calls a command called `\getpagewiselinenumber` on the current line number:

```
\def\thePagewiseLineNumber{\protect\getpagewiselinenumber{\the\c@linenumber}}
```

The macro `\getpagewiselinenumber` starts a group, stores its argument (a "document-wise" line number) into `\c@linenumber`, then calls the misleadingly named macro `\testNumberedPage`, which calculates the page-wise line number and stores the result back into `\c@linenumber`. Then it prints out the value of `\c@linenumber` and ends the group to restore the original value of `\c@linenumber`.

```
\def\getpagewiselinenumber#1{{% extra brace makes assignments local
    \c@linenumber #1\relax % store argument (a document-wise line number) in \c@linenumber
    \testNumberedPage % calculate page-wise line number, store result in \c@linenumber
    \thelinenumber % print \c@linenumber
}} % end the group to restore \c@linenumber
```

In my opinion, this is crappy code. Why is `\c@linenumber` used for storing 1) the actual current line number 2) the input value and 3) the output value? If you fail to restore `\c@linenumber` at the end, it corrupts the `.aux` file and tex hangs the next time you run it. Also, as you discovered, this design makes it impossible for the user of the package to do anything with the calculated value other than directly print it. It should store the output value into some well-named output macro and then let the user do what they want with it.

Anyways, now that we understand how the package works, it's easy enough to write our own function to test the current page.

```
% #1 -- a macro to store the pagewise line number into 
\def\storepagewiselineno#1{%
   \bgroup % This group is to keep the value of \c@linenumber local
   \testNumberedPage % store the page-wise line number into \c@linenumber
   \xdef#1{\the\c@linenumber}% globally store the page-wise line number in #1
   \egroup % restore the value of \c@linenumber
}
```

As an alternative, if you like to avoid making global definitions, you can use the following version, which uses a standard trick to "smuggle" the value of `\c@linenumber` out of the scope with a chain of `\expandafter`s. (pgf defines a macro called `\pgfmathsmuggle` that lets you say `\pgfmathsmuggle\somemacro\endgroup` and does this automatically).

```
\def\storepagewiselineno#1{%
   \bgroup 
   \testNumberedPage 
   \expandafter\egroup % smuggle \c@linenumber out of the group with an \expandafter chain
   \expandafter\edef\expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\c@linenumber}% 
}
```

Here's the full code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\pagewiselinenumbers
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\color{gray!50}}
\makeatletter
\def\storepagewiselineno#1{%
    \bgroup % This group is to keep the value of \c@linenumber local
    \testNumberedPage % store the page-wise line number into \c@linenumber
    \expandafter\egroup % smuggle \c@linenumber out of the scope
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter#1\expandafter{\the\c@linenumber}%
}
\makeatother


\def\testinglinenumber{\noindent
    Line \thePagewiseLineNumber\ (\thelinenumber\ in global count) ---
    \storepagewiselineno\temp
    \ifnum\temp>1\relax I am NOT in first line\else I am in first line\fi\par
}

\begin{document}
\testinglinenumber  
\testinglinenumber  
{\color{gray!50} \lipsum[1-4] More text \par More text \par }

\newpage

\testinglinenumber  
\testinglinenumber 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I half-understood the problem and played with  `\testNumberedPage` and `\c@linenumber` (and all others` \c@...` counters) without hit the key. BTW,  why you show  two different versions of   `\storepagewiselineno`?  There are some reason to change it in the MWE or it is simply a matter of taste?

Comment: @Fran Oh sorry that was a mistake. I'll add an explanation for the second version.